# PHP - Why is echo printing it like zeros?

Tags: php, get

A very simple code in php

```
<?php

$aaa    = $_GET["aaa"];
echo $aaa + "\n";

$bbb    = $_GET["bbb"];
echo $bbb+ "\n";

$ccc    = $_GET["ccc"];
echo $ccc+ "\n";
```

the URL calling this

```
http://example.com?aaa=AAA&bbb=BBB&ccc=CCC
```

the result is completely blank. Nothing gets printed.

If I change the echos to

```
echo (string) ($aaa + "\n");
echo (string) ($bbb + "\n");
echo (string) ($ccc + "\n");
```

then the result is

```
000
```

Why?

Comment: Because you are adding, not concatenating those values. `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP. PHP is using type juggling because of this and your strings become their integer equivalents which is zero and thus zero plus zero equals zero which is what you see in your output.

Comment: sorry about that. I was programming in javascript at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different from JS or Python for example, where the string concatenate sign is a "`+`", in PHP it is a "`.`", "`+`" in PHP is used for numerical sums. Try this:

```
<?php

$aaa = $_GET["aaa"];
echo $aaa . "\n";

$bbb = $_GET["bbb"];
echo $bbb . "\n";

$ccc = $_GET["ccc"];
echo $ccc . "\n";
```